# requireNamespaceQuietStop causing errors in custom summaryFunction caret

Tags: r, function, r-caret

I 'updated' the twoClassSummary function in caret to include both the negative and positive predictive values using caret functions:

```
testfun <- function (data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) 
{
  lvls <- levels(data$obs)
  if (length(lvls) > 2) 
    stop(paste("Your outcome has", length(lvls), "levels. The 
twoClassSummary() function isn't appropriate."))
  requireNamespaceQuietStop("ModelMetrics")
  if (!all(levels(data[, "pred"]) == lvls)) 
    stop("levels of observed and predicted data do not match")
  data$y = as.numeric(data$obs == lvls[2])
  rocAUC <- ModelMetrics::auc(ifelse(data$obs == lev[2], 0, 
                                     1), data[, lvls[1]])
  out <- c(rocAUC, sensitivity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[1]), 
                   specificity(data[, "pred"], data[, "obs"], lev[2]),
                   # next 3 lines are my additions and modifications
                   negPredValue(data[, "obs"], data[, "pred"], lev[2]),
                   posPredValue(data[, "obs"], data[, "pred"], lev[1]))
  names(out) <- c("ROC", "Sens", "Spec", "NPV", "PPV")
  out
}
```

And then my trainControl function:

```
train_control <- trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv', 
                              number = 10, repeats = 3,
                              summaryFunction = testfun,
                              classProbs = T,
                              savePredictions = T)
```

and then my model function:

```
modelSvm <- train(target ~ ., data = twoClassData, trControl = train_control, method = 'svmRadial')
```

The problem is when I run this function, I get the error 
Error in ctrl$summaryFunction(testOutput, lev, method) : 
  could not find function "requireNamespaceQuietStop"

even though I haven't change that part of the function.

if I type

```
twoClassSummary
```

in the console,

environment: namespace:caret

appears (between < > signs) at the end after the function definition and I believe this is the source of my problems.

1) How do I direct R to this environment in the function? and
2) accuracy is not a predefined caret function, any suggestions on how to work accuracy into this code?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function is not exported by `caret`, so use `caret::: requireNamespaceQuietStop` instead (or use used `library`).

Comment: Thanks so much! I eventually figured it out through some googling. I thought it would be caret::

Comment: I don't know the use used library method, do you have a reference for that? Thanks again!